# Is there a way to transfer a CCSprite child to another parent?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

If I have a CCSprite that has previously been added to a parent CCNode or CCLayer, is there any way to change its parent object?

I tried doing:

```
[self setParent:newParent];
```

...

and then:

```
[parent removeChild:self cleanup:YES];
[newParent addChild:self];
```

Neither works...  THe latter actually causes a crash.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that in the second case you added autoreleased object to the parent. In this case sprite will be deleted after removing from parent, so you will not be able to add it to another parent. Try this

```
[self retain];
[self removeFromParentWithCleanup:YES];
[newParent addChild: self];
[self release];
```

And in the case of crash with error, post the crash message in future. It can help to figure out problem.

Comment: I did not think autoreleased objects are cleaned that fast (ie. the cleanup is part of the runloop cycling process). See note above for the crash reason.

Comment: AFAIK, autoreleased object receives release message at the end of the tick where it was added to the autorelease pool =) anyway, you can try to retain autoreleased object, then in any other tick release it and try to use it as object) I think you will get error =)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you first remove (NO cleanup), then add to new parent, it should work.

Comment: isnt doing NO cleanup simply saying for it not to call "stopAllActions" ?  Why would cleanup:YES cause it to not work?

Comment: true, actions and scheduled selectors are maintained. What kind of 'crash' are you getting when doing your option 2 ? is CCNode whining (look at the log) ? You must pay attention in the child-parent relationship to CCSpriteBatchNodes. In that case, both parents and the child must stem from the same texture.

Comment: I get this:  'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Delegate already added to touch dispatcher.'  So, I guess when a sprite is added as a child, it's onEnter method is called which is now calling addTargetedDelegate on the touch dispatcher.  I was looking through the available methods and couldn't find any boolean property to determine if a node has already been added as a targeted delegate...

Comment: that would be beyond my knowledge of cocos inner workings. You could try to [[CCDirector sharedDispatcher].touchDispatcher forceRemoveDelegate:self], but i'm afraid you are going to go from one surprise to the next.

Comment: CCSprite is not added as any touch delegate at all by default. If you register it as touch delegate manually in your onEnter method, make sure that you remove it from touch delegates in your onExtir method